# How to save message coming from RabbitMQ into Redis Cache/DB?

Tags: java, redis, rabbitmq, microservices

I have one listener service in my microservice and two scheduler service. In the listener service after receiving the message save the last updated date time and scheduler name in  Redis DB.

Can anyone write a demo code for me?